# This code works in eclipse ide but not in my college's online ide for exams.How to make this work there too

Tags: java, eclipse, collections, nullpointerexception

This Aim of this program is to return the key in a map having maximum value.

This code works fine in Eclipse.

But returns these run time errors in my college's online ide for exams.
I tried my best guys.to sort this out...But i Can't.
can i anyone figure out what is the problem with this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;  
class Main{  
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
 Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
 Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);

HashMap<String,Double> hm=new HashMap<String,Double>();
 System.out.println("Enter the number of students ");
 int n=s.nextInt();
 s.nextLine();
 String[] name= new String[n];
 Double[] mark= new Double[n];


  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
  System.out.println("Enter the details of the student "+(i+1));
  name[i]=s.nextLine();
  if(e.hasNext())
  mark[i]=e.nextDouble();
  hm.put(name[i],mark[i]);  
  } 
  String maxKey = getMaxEntry(hm).getKey();
  System.out.println(maxKey);

  } 
  public static Entry<String, Double> getMaxEntry(Map<String, Double> map){        
    Entry<String, Double> maxEntry = null;
    Double max = Collections.max(map.values());

    for(Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Double value = entry.getValue();
        if(null != value && max == value) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
    return maxEntry;
     }
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:702) at
>   Main.getMaxEntry(Main.java:32) at Main.main(Main.java:26)

Comment: looks like map.values() is crashing, print out `map` at the beginning of the method, it might be null

Comment: I am so new to this.I can't get what you are saying.
Can u explain a bit.

Comment: at the beginning of your `getMaxEntry` method, add this line: 
`System.out.println("map: "+map);` . . If it prints `map: null` then this is your problem

Comment: by the way which line lis line 32 ?

Comment: `Double max = Collections.max(map.values());` is line 32

Comment: Yes Mr.Bentaye `System.out.println("map: "+map);` prints null

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: well, it shouldn't :) so make sure you build your map properly and it should work

Comment: Looking at your code, I can't see how your `hm` map can be null. Are you 100% sure this is the code that crashes?

Comment: Yes..
it runs fine on eclipse 
but crashes on online ide

Answer (score 0):

The following does not compare doubles, but objects:

```
max == value
```

It should be

```
value.equals(max);
```

As `Double` is the Object wrapper of a numeric type `double`.

And `max` might be null on an empty collection.

Comment: I Changed it to value.equals(max);
not still working
throws the same error :(

Comment: Dubious is `if(e.hasNext())` so that must be causing the error. You could make the array `double[] mark;` with small d (no nulls anymore). And check the input (hasNextDouble if-else).